# Failure to Submit App to Apple App Store - ITMS 9000 xCode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am unable to submit apps to the app store due the an error on app submission.  Getting the error ITMS 9000 Cannot submit apps with xCode 5.1.1.

I have validated that I am using the latest general public release available via the Mac App Store.

Comment: I solved this problem by changing the deployment target for this app from iOS 7.1 to iOS 7.0. After changing the deployment target, rebuilding the app and resubmitting the app, the submission process was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the deployment target for this app from iOS 7.1 to iOS 7.0. After changing the deployment target, rebuilding the app and resubmitting the app, the submission process was successful.